# SQL select with multiple different conditions

Tags: sql, cratedb

I am still learning SQL and can't find a proper way to find the following information:

I have created a table "employees" with the following columns:

'department', 'age', 'salary', 'bonus';

I am trying to design a query that will give me all employees that have someone the same age as them in another department and with a bonus superior to their salary.

(to be more precise, if someone in department 'SALES' has the same age as someone in department 'RESEARCH' and have a bonus that is superior to that guy in research's salary, then I would like to display both of them)

Is this possible to do in sql?

Thank you for your time,

-Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `exists`.  Because you care about the relationship in *both* direction, this is as simple as looking for people with the same age in the two departments but who do not have the same bonus:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where exists (select 1
              from employees e2
              where e2.department <> e.department and e2.age = e.age and
                    e2.bonus <> e.bonus
             );
```

To get the pairs on the same row, use a self-join:

```
select e1.*, e2.*
from employees e1 join
     employees e2
     on e1.age = e2.age and e1.department <> e2.department and
        e1.bonus > e2.bonus;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I did not realise you could use the same table twice as e1 and e2, this is very helpful.